# Android Camera.takePicture() saves pictures with 176x144 pixels

Tags: android, android-camera

I have programmed an App with a CameraPreview. When I take a Photo now, the App save it with 176 x 144 Pixels. Can I Change the width an the height? 
I use the Camera Api, not Camera2.

When I took photos with the normal Camera-App, it saved Images with 2368x4208 Pixels.

**This is where the Photos where taken**

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    Bitmap rawImg = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

    Log.e("TakePicture", "Picture Callback erreicht");

    shotAnalyser.startAnalysation(rawImg, data);
  }
```

**Here I grab the Data and make a Bitmap**

```
  public void startAnalysation(final Bitmap rawImg, final byte[] data){

        Bitmap rawBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

        // Ermitteln der nötigen Bild-Eigenschaften

        int width = rawBitmap.getWidth();
        int height = rawBitmap.getHeight();
      }
```

**Here I tried to Change the PictureSize**

```
    public Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
        c = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        Log.e(LOG, "CameraInstance: " + c + " RUNS");
        Camera.Parameters parameters = c.getParameters();
        parameters.set("jpeg-quality", 70);
        parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
        parameters.setPictureSize(2048, 1232);
        c.setParameters(parameters);

    }
    catch (Exception e){
    }

    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable

}
```

I've googled a lot, but I can't find anything.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. In this case, it would include the code where you are configuring either the `Camera.Parameters` for the classic `Camera` API or the equivalent for the `android.hardware.camera2` API.

Comment: I've added a bit of Code.

Comment: Please post the code where you are configuring the picture size in the `Camera.Parameters`.

Comment: I don't set Camera.Parameters. How can I configure the Picture-Size?

Comment: Sorry, I've posted the Code above.

Comment: @CommonsWare why did you delete answer? It's a good answer.